# Filter data table for multiple condition in UiPath

Tags: datatable, rpa, uipath

So I am using UiPath to automate a process by searching a DataTable on a specific column with a range of keywords. I know that we can use the `Filter Data Table` and add on the keywords that I want but I have about 130 keywords to be matched and it's troublesome to add one by one using the Filter Data Table function.

Is there any way that I can use like **creating a list** and **match the list** or something and give the output that matched?

Comment: You just need to wrap it with a for each. Can you share some screenshot and the Main.xaml file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Datatable.Select` to filter a datatable with multiple conditions fairly easily.

`myDataTable.Select("[Column x] Not in ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')")`

Will give you all the DataRows where the field in your datatable called Column X is not `value1`, `value2`, or `value3`